# How to storesome data after activity is destroyed

Tags: android, xml

I am creating a calculator application, when my activity is sent to background and then brought to front.The result in it becomes zero. How can i save the data nd retrive it next time hen activity is recreated.

Comment: Give us more to go on...

Answer (score 0):

Use `SharedPreferences` like :

```
SharedPreferences preferences = null;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
}
```

in `onDestory()`  write :

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(YOUR_KEY, YOUR_VALUE);
    editor.commit();
}
```

and in `onStart()` write :

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    int result = preferences.getInt(YOUR_KEY, YOUR_VALUE);
}
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

For that specific case, you want to use the [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) lifecycle methods `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`. Override both those methods, and then save the necessary data in `onSaveInstanceState`. In the `onCreate` or the `onRestoreInstanceState` check for the existence of the saved data and then restore it to the right place.

Note: you can use preferences or a database as well, but those are generally to be used for data that should last more than a single background/restore cycle. The `onSaveInstanceState`/`onRestoreInstanceState` methods are specifically for the case where an Activity gets sent to the background and then restored later.